# Save data to file in a file system using fs in Nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, fs

I want to save data to a file in a local file system.

the action what i want to implement is when a button click happens the data should pass to the back end and save the data using fs.

i have a fs code which is working fine.

```
 var fs = require("fs");
 var path = "D:\\Temp\\Test.txt";
 var data = "Hello";

 fs.writeFile(path, data, function(error) {
 if (error) {
   console.error("write error:  " + error.message);
 } else {
   console.log("Successful Write to " + path);
 }
 });
```

then i used above fs code in my developing as below.

angular front end Controller

```
$scope.sendToBack = function ()
{
     var csvData = {
                   dat: str
                   };           

       Event.postDataToCepFs(csvData)
           .success(function () {
               $scope.status = 'Reading the selected file';

           })
           .error(function (error) {
              $scope.status = 'Unable to insert data: ' ;
           });


    return str;

   };
```

FrontEnd Service Layer

```
  postDataToCepFs : function(event) {
        return $http.post('/api/sendDataToCepFs', event);
        $window.location.reload();
    },
```

Backend Route

```
app.post('/api/sendDataToCepFs', function(req, res) {

        var path = "D:\\Test.txt";        

          fs.writeFile(path, res.body.dat, function(error) {
               if (error) {
                 console.error("write error:  " + error.message);
               } else {
                 console.log("Successful Write to " + path);
               }
          });        
     });
```

The above is my approach.but it gives "*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)*"

can anyone help me this this?

Thanks

Comment: Any error in node.js's console?

Comment: What's the type of `res.body.dat`?

Comment: yea. i didn't specify the type of res.body.dat.now its fixed.Thanks @Omri Luzon

Answer (score 2):

Are you using any middleware? 
Multer will work fine. Find below the links for multer documentation and sample.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

http://lollyrock.com/articles/express4-file-upload/

Comment: Thanks @M.Navy! it's fixed.